# Azure VM:: Programmatically how to get vcpus and GiB memory of the virtual machine corresponding to a vm size

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python, azure-rest-api

Programmatically how to get vcpus and GiB memory of the virtual machine corresponding to a vm size.I am using python code to get the details,so is there any API or azure python sdk available to get above details.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: It helps very much, thanks Charles Xu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Python SDK to list all the available VM size in your region and get the same one as you use:

```
region = "xxxx"
current_vmSize = "xxxxx"
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_Id)
vmSizes = compute_client.virtual_machine_sizes.list(region)
for vmSize in vmSizes:
  if vmSize.name == current_vmSize:
    print("vCPU: ", vmSize.number_of_cores)
    print("memory: ", vmSize.memory_in_mb)
```

You can get more details about the [VM size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.virtualmachinesizesoperations?view=azure-python) in the Python SDK. And you can replace the variable with the exact thing that you get with your code.